# Flash - page flip which allows site users to create their own book

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

as the title suggests, I'm looking for a Flash page flipper which I can integrate with an existing database of users and allow them to create their own flash books - I don't need anything complex as this isn't a CSS, just something which allows users to insert images and some text in each page. I've had a look at quite a few now and nothing is really suitable, so i thought i'd try here in case anyone had a suggestion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a Flash-based WYSIWYG editor where a user could place his own images and text on a page, that page would then be exported as a PNG, and that PNG would then be loaded by a Flash-based flip book. I'm afraid that there is nothing similar currently available for free or for money, and unless you have experience working in AS3 it won't be that easy for you to make such a project. If you think that this could be a viable project for your website, I think that your best bet is to hire a professional AS3 developer to make this for you (and it won't be cheap).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose [Emag Creator](http://www.emagcreator.com/) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to insert images to page flip flash, suggest you use aximg, it can edit your photos to flipping photo book.

But if you need convert images and some text in each page, you can edit the image page first and save to pdf, then use online pdf to page flip flash service to achieve that, many websites supply this free conversion service, such as http://data.axmag.com/submit.html